# присвоение атрубуту img src значение переменной php

Tags: php

помогите, почему отображается вместо картинки пустой квадрат.

```
<?php
    $S='http://shop/images/60_srt.JPg';
    echo "<img style = "height:130px; width:170px;" src = $S border=1>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Картинка по данному адресу не доступна: Не удается получить доступ к сайту

Кавычки одинарные нужны

```
<?php
$S='https://i.pinimg.com/736x/3a/32/fb/3a32fb5c1dffe1a25016014e6bf97471.jpg';
echo "<img style = 'height:130px; width:170px;' src = '$S' border='1'>";?>
```